# What Python object to model set data

Tags: python

I'm looking for the most efficient data objects in Python to model the following data.

Basically there is always going to be an attribute and then an include and exclude list. It is for a shipping program.

For example:

```
[
 {
   "attribute": "country", 
   "exclude": ["North Korea"],
 },
 {
   "attribute": "hazardous", 
   "include": ["liquid"], 
 },
]
```

The idea being all countries bar North Korea are allowed to be shipped to but no hazardous items except liquids are allowed to be dispatched.

I attempted to have a list of dictionary with two sets (include and exclude) but it ended up with a lot of `if X in Y then`  type code which I don't think is efficient.

Comment: Looks like JSON would suffice and maybe just import this into Python/pandas DFs?

Comment: Sets will be more efficient than lists or tuples for a large number of elements, or for repeated access.  For small quantities or one-off access it may be more efficient to use linear search rather than pay the cost of hashing the elements.  Either way you will be doing `if X in Y` somewhere.